# Redirect from subfolder to main domain with different port

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, raspberry-pi, webcam

For christmas i got a raspberry pi and i want it to use it among other things as a ip cam. So i googled how to use a webcam and found a tutorial how to use motion. Worked all fine.

Now i have the follwing "problem":

I can access the webcam via `<domain>:1337`. But i want to access the webcam via `<domain>/webcam`.

I googled some stuff about htaccess but i couldn't solve the problem since i'm fairly new to the htacces stuff.

I actived htaccess in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` and created a .
htaccess file in `/var/www/`.

Any idea what to write to the htacces file or how to tell motion to be available in the subfolder?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: port 80 and port 1337 share the same document root ?

Comment: yes! both have /var/www/ as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^webcam$ http://<domain>.com:1337/ [P]
```

Note: make sure **mod_rewrite** and **mod_proxy** are enabled

Comment: do i necessary need mod_proxy? because when i try to enable it with sudo a2enmod mod_prxy it says module not found? and do i have to note something when i'm using a subdomain? something like test.domain.com?

Comment: Well since both 80 and 1337 share the same document root, technically you could avoid using *mod_proxy* but i don't have enough information on how your webcam works (what is executed when you reach http://domain:1337/ ?)

Comment: i followed this tutorial:http://m.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-remote-webcam/?lang=de so i gues it's only a small webserver... sorry for providing just the mobile version

Comment: Ok. I think it's better to use *mod_proxy* then. Try `a2enmod proxy` to enable it